# synchronous datatable update from other assembly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

When I update datatable from other assembly process is to fast for updating datatable ; for example;
I have 3 layer assembly as follows ;

Framework.dll

Bussiness.dll

Win.UI.dll

When I call `framework.updatetable(dt as Datatable)` in Win.UI.dll assembly, function return successful  but requery datatable in Win.UI.dll layer data table not  changed. And I try with debugger or waiting process like a `Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)`  (slow moition) return updated datatable .
Actualy there is no problem in phisical update in database , datatable is updated all case, but i thing so update process is asynchronous also process is to fast...

How can I synchronized this situation. Thanks for all help...
Hakan Örnek

Ps :
Enviroments =  Database in Ms Access / Framework 4.0  / VS 2010